# Trouble Copying Formatting from Conditionally Formatted Cells

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013, conditional-formatting

I have a simple column of names, with conditional formatting based on another column of TRUE/FALSE values.  The TRUE/FALSE column is calculated using vlookups based on other columns.

I need to present the worksheet in a clean manner to collegues, so I need to be able to remove all the calculated columns, vlookups and so on, but keep the final formatting.

I can easily enough copy the formatting and values to another worksheet, but as soon as I remove the original TRUE/FALSE column, the formatting disappears on the copied cells.

Is there any way to simply copy the conditional formatting and also remove the original calculated cells? I've tried all the Paste Special options without much luck.

Comment: As you have found, the formatting goes away as soon as you remove the condition. There doesn't appear to be a way to copy with the formatting as you described. As an alternative, have you considered hiding the columns you do not want seen and export to PDF? This would allow them to see the formatted sheet, but not the areas you don't want them to. It would also keep them from unhiding the columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested, you can hide the True/False column or move it to the last column and make the text white so that it does not show.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to those that suggested a solution.

I gave up on using conditional formatting, and instead came up with a VBA macro to perform the same function as the conditional formatting:

```
Sub ConditionalFormat()
    Dim lRow As Long

    For lRow = 1 To 100
        If Cells(lRow, 2).Value = True Then
            Cells(lRow, 1).Font.Bold = True
            With Cells(lRow, 1).Interior
                .Pattern = xlSolid
                .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent6
                .TintAndShade = 0.799981688894314
                .PatternTintAndShade = 0
            End With
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

This allowed me to remove the calculated columns, without affecting the final formatting.

This may be useful to others suffering from the same problem.